# on('request') called twice on every request, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have simple node js code that returns a JSON string on UI if promise is successfully resolved, else it with show error on UI.

```
const server = require('http').createServer();

server.on('request', (request, response) => {

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var jsonInput = '{"result":true, "count":42}';

        resolve(JSON.parse(jsonInput));

    }).then((data) => {

      response.end(JSON.stringify(data));

    }).catch((err) => {

      response.end(String(err));

    });

    console.log('received a request');

});

server.listen(8000);
```

Why the `'received a request'` is printed twice? Does browser sends a second request automatically or my code is buggy?

Comment: It looks like you're experimenting with writing a web backend in Node.js. You can absolutely do that with just the built-in stuff as you are above, but FWIW, at some point you might want to look at [koa](http://koajs.com) or [Express](http://expressjs.com). They've done a lot of the boring work for you (and have plugins to do all kinds of things). Happy coding!

Comment: Actually, you are correct, I use Meteor js. But I am trying to learn and get little deep into raw Node JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the 'received a request' is printed twice?

Most likely, because your browser sent two requests. Chrome does that the first time you connect, for instance, sending first a request for the URL you actually asked for, and also a request for `favicon.ico`. Look at `request.url` to see what the requests are for.

For instance, if I take your code and put it in a file, and change the `console.log` line to:

```
console.log('received a request: ' + request.url);
```

When I connect to `http://localhost:8000/`, I see:

```
received a request: /
received a request: /favicon.ico
```